# jquery error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i am using jquery plugin for upload content. but when i uploading a content there is a error show that unexpected end of input. here is the code snippet

```
  function uploadPacket(packet){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = self.url + "?fileid="+self.fileDetails.fileId+"&token="+self.fileDetails.token+"&packet="+self.fileDetails.currentPackage;
    //alert(url);
    var fileDetails = self.fileDetails;
    updateProgress(fileDetails,0);
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onprogress = function(e){
        updateProgress(fileDetails,e.position);

    // var percentComplete = (e.position / e.totalSize)*100;
    //console.log(percentComplete);
    //   progressBar.value = percentComplete;
    //  loadedSize.innerHTML = e.position;
    // speed.innerHTML = ((e.position-startedBytes)/1024)/((new Date().getTime()-timer)/1000)+ " kbps";

    };

    /**
     * If the server uploaded the packet successfully, then go to updateDetails() where log the success,
     * and initiate uploading the next package (if we not paused while it uploaded)
     */
    xhr.onload = function (e){
        //alert(e);
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);  // here is the error showing

        if (response.action=="new_packet" && response.result=="success"){                
            updateDetails(fileDetails);
        }      

    }; 


    xhr.send(packet);
}
```

please anyone help me

Comment: That's not valid JSON, whatever's being returned as the `responseText`, it's a syntax parsing error in this case. Please show us the string you expect back.

Comment: it working fine in mozila only issue in chrome